# Spark scala how to convert a Integer column in dataframe to hex uppercase string?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We can use the following function to covert a single integer value.

```
val x=100
Integer.toString(x, 16).toUpperCase
```

But how to apply it to a integer column to generate a new column with hex string? thanks!

The below method does not work.

```
testDF = testDF.withColumn("data_hex_string", Integer.toString(testDF("data"), 16).toUpperCase)
```

Comment: check https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#conv

Comment: Thanks, it is very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't a spark native function, so make a udf function to do that.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def toHex = udf((int: Int) => java.lang.Integer.toString(int, 16).toUpperCase)

df.withColumn("hex", toHex($"int")).show()

+---+---+---+
| id|int|hex|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|
|  2| 11|  B|
|  3| 23| 17|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

As @jxc already mentioned in a comment, use the [`conv` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#conv):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{conv, lower}
df.withColumn("hex", conv($"int_col",10,16)).show
```

For those who want lowercase, wrap it with `lower`:

```
df.withColumn("hex", lower(conv($"int_col",10,16))).show
```